# Get Specific folder access/permission only in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have published the app on the Google play store with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Google rejected the app and said to remove this permission and get access to a specific folder (related to your app, not the entire storage permission)

I have used the `react-native-scoped-storage` for this purpose and followed the documentation. With this line:

```
let dir = await ScopedStorage.openDocumentTree(true);
```

The file manager opened and I granted permission, but still, I am unable to get files.

I do get files with this same package with this line:

```
const files = await ScopedStorage.listFiles(dir.uri);
```

But the format is not correct, I get data in this format:

```
"uri": "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2Fmedia%2F.Statuses/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2Fmedia%2F.Statuses"
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with a nice content scheme? Use it!

Comment: Hi @blackapps, Can you explain it? I am new to react native, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A content scheme has nothing to do with react native. But all with the use of saf picking a document tree.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you refer to any article or question on StackOverflow, so I can read about it?